# Asp.net MVC 3 FullCalendar Ajax calls fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

My simple test application works great off my local IIS server.
When I publish it my shared hosting environment (discountasp.net),  The AJAX call

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            eventSources: [{
                url: '/Home/GetCurrentMonth',
                type: 'Get',
                error: function () {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                }
            }]

        });
```

fails.  Firebug shows the get arriving with the proper params and gives a '404 Not Found' error.  And I can see that the controller method 'GetCurrentMonth' is never being called (with some log\audit code I put in).

As everything runs fine on my local IIS server and I can't connect with IIS7 Manager to the remote site to get a  'Failed Request Tracing'..  I'm kind of stuck.

If there is no magic web.config setting (oh please!) I would settle for a recommendation of a 'shared hosting environment'  that supports ASP.NET MVC 3 where FullCalendar works and I'd move the application (my current hosting environment has been way less than helpful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never hardcode urls as you did. Always use url helpers when generating urls in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [{
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCurrentMonth", "Home")',
        type: 'GET',
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
    }]
});
```

Or if this is in a separate javascript file in which you don't have access to server side code one possibility is to use for example HTML5 data-* attributes, like this:

```
<div id="calendar" data-url="@Url.Action("GetCurrentMonth", "Home")"></div>
```

and then in your separate javascript file:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [{
        url: $('#calendar').data('url'),
        type: 'GET',
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
    }]
});
```

I bet 50 bucks the reason why your code doesn't work when you deployed it is because there is a virtual directory appended by IIS. So the correct url is not `/Home/GetCurrentMonth` but `/YourApplicationName/Home/GetCurrentMonth`. To avoid all those problems you should always use helpers when generating urls.

Comment: "there is a virtual directory appended by IIS", are you sure? A search for "site:discountasp.net" returned many hits using subdomains instead (eg. stocks.paul.discountasp.net)

Comment: @bzlm, no I am not sure, I don't know this hosting site, but given the symptoms I bet 50 bucks that this is his problem. 404 errors when moving to production => in 99.999999% of the cases that's due to hardcoded urls.

Comment: @darin, I meant that if this is the only thing that doesn't work, and the application is in a virtual directory, then this must be the only place where hardcoded paths are used - otherwise, no links would have worked. But it seems it was. (: